# Como pongo un espacio entre numeros binarios en C++ cada 4 digitos?

Tags: c++, binario

Muy buenas, verán, se me asignó un inciso en una tarea en el cual se me pide realizar conversión de decimal a binario, de ahí todo bien, pero cuando llego a la parte en la que me pide que si el numero se extiende de 4 digitos (1000 0001) se haga una separación entre estos, cada 4 digitos.

Tengo el codigo a mano, en el cual el ejercicio funciona, he buscado varias formas de hacer esto, pero no he encontrano ninguno.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

long long convert(int);

int main() {
  int n, bin;
  cout << "Enter a decimal number: ";
  cin >> n;
  bin = convert(n);
  cout << n << " in decimal = " << bin << " in binary" << endl ;
  return 0;
}

long long convert(int n) {
  long long bin = 0;
  int rem, i = 1;

  while (n!=0) {
    rem = n % 2;
    n /= 2;
    bin += rem * i;
    i *= 10;
  }

  return bin;
}
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda y atención, de antemano.

Comment: Usar un entero no es muy práctico para guardar números binarios, qué tal un `vector<bool>` o incluso [`bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

Comment: @Mateo, tienes razón que no es funcional el usar un entero, al final, llegué a una solución un tanto distinta, agradezco tu comentario y ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final rearmé el codigo y encontré una forma mas practica de realizar este ejercicio, dejo solución para aquellos que la necesiten en el futuro por venir.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void convDecBin(int d){

    int r[32];
    int i=0;

    while (d>0){
        r[i] = d%2;
        i++;
        d = d/2;
    }

    for (i--; i>=0; i--){
        cout << r[i];
        if(i%4 == 0){
            cout << " ";
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int d;
    do{
        cout << "valor en decimal: ";
        cin >> d;

        convDecBin(d);
    }while (d != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

En este caso, la solución al problema viene a ser que un contador calcula, si la división del ejercicio calcula hasta que el residuo de la división de los valores entre 4, de resultado 0, cuando esto ocurre, este separa después del cuarto dígito.

```
if(i%4 == 0){
   cout << " ";
}
```

Comment: Agradezco el comentario, al final encontré una solución alterna. No se puede aceptar una respuesta que ha sido recientemente escrita si no ha pasado una hora. Una disculpa @padaleiana.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo tienes como `long long`, divide entre 10.000 para hacer grupos de 4 dígitos. El problema es que los grupos los vas a obtener al revés de como esperas imprimirlos. Para corregir este aspecto puedes guardarlos en un contenedor para recorrerlos posteriormente en orden inverso:

```
std::vector<int> grupos;
while (bin != 0)
{
    grupos.push_front(static_cast<int>(bin % 10000));
    bin /= 10000;
}

for (int grupo : grupos)
{
    cout << grupo << ' ';
}
```

Otra opción sería guardar el dato binario directamente en un `string`, por ejemplo, y luego trocearlo a conveniencia

Comment: Agradezco tu ayuda, no pude probar tu solución. Pero agradezco que te hayas tomado la molestia de inclinarte a ayudarme.